# Anyone have trouble with heroku maintenance:on

Tags: heroku

I have used `heroku maintenance:on` before and it took a little bit to change to maintenance mode. Now it doesn't seem to work at all. What's going on here?

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't "seem to work at all"? Are you getting an error? Is it taking a while? What's up?

Comment: no erros, it says that maintenance is enabled after I enable it it just does change the application into the appropriate mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean when you said it "doesn't seem to work at all" ?

I just tried on one of my app and it seems to work just fine.

According to [Heroku's official documentation regarding maintenance mode](http://docs.heroku.com/maintenance-mode), maintenance mode will make Heroku serve a static page (usually says 'Application Offline for Maintenance') until you disable the maintenance mode.

Comment: I switched on Heroku maintenance mode and now it is not switching off. The command HEROKU MAINTENANCE says its off however website reroutes to maintenance page and logs have H80. Any one found any solution?